# Wrong view size in viewWillTransition method when rotating

Tags: ios, swift

I use viewWillTransition to change frame of a view, and if my ViewController is top most then all is fine, here is printed frame upon rotation

```
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 476.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 476.0) / rotate
```

Issue happens when i rotate screen when my ViewController is not top most, for example some ViewController is presented/pushed over it. I still receive notification in this method but size in not good.

```
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
TEST frame: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 732.0) / rotate
```

I have to set up view with frame because i am using [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) library. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I did managed to resolve this issue by using didLayoutSubviews method and changing frame there.

Comment: but `didLayoutSubviews` is called many times and not only when rotation happens...